# The minimax algorithm for tic-tac-toe does not work correctly

Tags: java, android-studio

The problem is that the bot puts the zeros one after the other, and does not choose the best option for it. He has a chance not to lose, but he stubbornly ignores my next victory. It may seem silly, but I haven't been able to solve this problem for 4 days. Stackoverflow is probably the last chance for me to solve this problem.
I have 2 main classes: GameLogic and TicTacToeBoard. In Tic Tac Toe Board, the logic of the bot's move is executed. The field is represented by a two-dimensional array. Player 1 is a human, 2 is a bot.
I update the field using the update Game Board and setCell methods. the check Res method checks the state of the game.

Here are the main parts of the code I use. sry it a lot

```
class GameLogic{
private int[][] gameBoard;
private int player = 1;
//1st element —> row, 2nd element —> col, 3rd —> line type
private int[] wintype = {-1, -1, -1};

public boolean updateGameBoard(int row, int col, boolean show){ //works if cell is empty
        if(gameBoard[row-1][col-1] == 0){ //if cell is empty
            gameBoard[row-1][col-1] = player; //a cell number is assigned
            if(player == 1 && show){ //if human
                playerTurn.setText(playerNames[1] + "'s turn");
            }
            else if(player == 2 && show){ //if bot
                playerTurn.setText(playerNames[0] + "'s turn");
            }
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
public String checkRes(){
        boolean isWinner = false;
        for(int r=0; r<3; r++){
            if(gameBoard[r][0] == gameBoard[r][1] && gameBoard[r][0] == gameBoard[r][2] && gameBoard[r][0] != 0){
                wintype = new int[]{r, 0, 1};
                isWinner = true;
            }
        }
        for(int c=0; c<3; c++){
            if(gameBoard[0][c] == gameBoard[1][c] && gameBoard[2][c] == gameBoard[0][c] && gameBoard[0][c] != 0){
                wintype = new int[]{0, c ,2};
                isWinner = true;
            }
        }
        if(gameBoard[0][0] == gameBoard[1][1] && gameBoard[0][0] == gameBoard[2][2] && gameBoard[0][0] != 0){
            wintype = new int[]{0, 2 ,3};
            isWinner = true;
        }
        else if(gameBoard[2][0] == gameBoard[1][1] && gameBoard[2][0] == gameBoard[0][2] && gameBoard[2][0] != 0){
            wintype = new int[]{2, 2 ,4};
            isWinner = true;
        }
        int boardFilled = 0;
        for(int r=0; r<3; r++){
            for(int c=0; c<3; c++){
                if(gameBoard[r][c] != 0){
                    boardFilled++;
                }
            }
        }
        if(isWinner){
            return "Won";
        }
        else if(boardFilled == 9){
            return "Tie";
        }else{
            return "Continue";
        }
    }
    public void showWin(){
        playAgainBTN.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        homeBTN.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        playerTurn.setText((playerNames[player-1] + " Won!"));

    }
    public void showTie(){
        playAgainBTN.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        homeBTN.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        playerTurn.setText("Tie game!");
    }
}
```

```
class TicTacToeBoard{
   private final GameLogic game;
   private boolean winningLine = false;
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) { //the code for processing the course of the game tic-tac-toe
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        int action = event.getAction();

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && game.getPlayer() == 1) {
            int row = (int) Math.ceil(y / cellSize);
            int col = (int) Math.ceil(x / cellSize);

            if (!winningLine) {
                if (game.updateGameBoard(row, col, true)) { //if there is an empty space, it assigns a value to this cell
                    invalidate();
                    if(game.checkRes().equals("Won")) {
                        winningLine = true;
                        game.showWin();
                    }
                    if(game.checkRes().equals("Tie")){
                        game.showTie();
                    }
                    game.setPlayer(2);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        else if (game.getPlayer() == 2) {
            hardDifficult();
        }
        return false;
    }
private void hardDifficult(){
        int[] bestMove = findBestMove();
        num1 = bestMove[0];
        num2 = bestMove[1];
        if(!winningLine){
            if(game.updateGameBoard(bestMove[0] + 1, bestMove[1] + 1, true)){
                invalidate();
                if(game.checkRes().equals("Won")){
                    winningLine = true;
                    game.showWin();

                }
                if(game.checkRes().equals("Tie")){
                    game.showTie();
                }
                game.setPlayer(1);
            }
        }
    }
    private int[] findBestMove() {
        int bestScore = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int[] bestMove = new int[2];
        for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
                if (game.updateGameBoard(r + 1, c + 1,false)){
                    int score = minimax(0, false);
                    game.setCell(r,c,0);
                    if (score > bestScore) {
                        bestScore = score;
                        bestMove[0] = r;
                        bestMove[1] = c;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return bestMove;
    }

    private int minimax(int depth, boolean isMaximizing) {
        if (game.checkRes().equals("Won")) {
            showInfo[0] = evaluateScore();
            return evaluateScore();
        }

        if (isMaximizing) {
            int bestScore = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
                    if (game.updateGameBoard(r + 1, c + 1, false)){
                        int score = minimax(depth+1, false);
                        game.setCell(r,c,0);
                        bestScore = Math.max(score, bestScore);
                    }
                }
            }
            return bestScore;
        } else {
            int bestScore = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
                    if (game.updateGameBoard(r + 1, c + 1, false)){
                        int score = minimax(depth+1, true);
                        game.setCell(r,c,0);
                        bestScore = Math.min(score, bestScore);
                    }
                }
            }
            return bestScore;
        }
    }

    private int evaluateScore() {

        if (game.checkRes().equals("Won") && game.getPlayer() == 2) {
// AI won
            return 10;
        } else if (game.checkRes().equals("Won") && game.getPlayer() == 1) {
// Player won
            return -10;
        } else if (game.checkRes().equals("Tie")) {
// Game tied
            return 0;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

I tried to use chatGPT many times, fixed his code, but it still does not work. I checked guides and rewrite their code but it still does not work..

Comment: Please do provide a complete compilable code!

Comment: can i send link on my app at github? It will be not work if i sent full code because i work in android studio. https://github.com/Xinox1231/TicTacToe